# Get the value of a field after bookmodel.objects.filter(title='X')

Tags: django

I'm trying to get title field value In the following way on Django 1.7.4 and python 2.7 :

```
def myview(request):
   myvar=bookmodel.objects.filter(title='masood')
   mytitle=myvar['title']
   print(mytitle)
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters

Answer (score 1):

`filter()` returns a list of instances:

```
books = bookmodel.objects.filter(title='masood')
for book in books:
    print book.title
```

If you want to get the first book with such title then use the `first()` method:

```
book = bookmodel.objects.filter(title='masood').first()
if book:
    print book.title
else:
    print 'Book not found'
```

If you are sure that one (and only one) instance of  such book exists then you can use the `get()` method:

```
book = bookmodel.objects.get(title='masood')
print book.title
```

But if such book doesn't exist or there is more that one book with such title then the exception will be thrown.